# How can I change the object's texture from ARKit app?

Tags: ios, textures, arkit

The object is in scene and I want when I press a button to change it's texture in real time. Is it possible?
I've tried like that but it doesn't work.

```
VirtualObjectsManager.shared.getVirtualObjectSelected()?.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose this is your object:

```
let obj = SCNNode()
obj.name = "obj1" // set a name, so you can access your object node later
```

First, set a name for your object's material:

```
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.name = "BackgroundImage" // set a name for the material
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "texture1.jpg")

obj.geometry?.materials = [material]
```

Then, in your button press method, you need an instance of the object:

```
let node = sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "obj1", recursively: true)
```

Then you can change it's texture:

```
let material = node.geometry?.material(named: "BackgroundImage")
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "texture2.jpg")
```